finding an example of ring $R$ and idempotent $e\in R$, such that $eR$ will not be submodule of $R$-module $R$
Let $R$ be a ring and $M$ left $R$-module. I now have trouble finding an example of ring $R$ and idempotent $e\in R$, such that $eR$ will not be submodule of $R$-module $R$. Any idea what to take?
I was only able to observe that for all $z\in Z(R)$ the set $zM=\{zm|m\in M\}$ is submodule od $M$.
Based on the comment bellow I took $R=M_2(\mathbb{R})$ and $M=\mathbb{R}^2$. Also, I took $e=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}$. But is then $eR$ submodule of $R$? How to check this?

Then you have to choose a noncentral idempotent. What's the simplest example of a ring with noncentral idempotents that comes to your mind?

Maybe the ring of matrices $M_n(\mathbb{R})$?

I edited my post, please have a look.

Did you find this in a well-known text?
